# Is it possible to log users out of my web app but keep them logged in with Facebook using Javascript sdk?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth, google-oauth

API page is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/v2.6

As far as I know,

If users have already authorized a web app(a website), then invoking `FB.login()` and `FB.logout()` in the web app is essentially **logging user in or out of Facebook and return the web app with some data**(of course you need access token to do this). Assume you have two pages opened, one is your web app, the other is `facebook.com`. Both logged out initially. Now if you log in with your Facebook account in the web app page, and then if you refresh the other page, you will find that both are logged in. It's similar for the case of logging out.

Well, correct me if my understanding is wrong. I totally understand there are reasons for the logic.

Is there a way to log out users from by web app but keep them logged in with the Facebook and without revoking permission?

I've tried with Google+ OAuth. It seems that using Google+ API is able to log out users from the web app and keep them logged in with Google+.

Comment: This is intended behavior. If the user visits an app again, that they authorized before already, and is logged into Facebook – then they should be seamlessly logged in to that app as well. If you don’t want that, then you can try initializing the SDK so that it does not check the login status on initialization, and offer the user a button to explicitly login instead.

Comment: @CBroe I kinda understand why it make sense. But for my situation, I want the user to be logged out of the web app instead of fb. I guess a common way is to have a user table of the web app itself. And bind a user to a fb account.

Comment: Exactly, you have to keep track of it yourself; even if that means something basic as storing their FB UI and access token into the session – so that you can only remove that session information when they log out from your site, but keep their FB login intact. (Side effect would be, that their access token does not get invalidated – so if anyone got to steal that, lets say via XSS or something, they would still be able to use it for as long until it expires by default.)

Answer (score 0):

Well it is how it should be. You want your app to be an interface for the "Facebook app" login, why is that? Consider the scenarios from the user's point of view-

1. User is logged-in and browsing facebook. He found the useful application of yours and login to your app(providing required permissions). Before leaving your app, he logouts from the app. He then gets back to the Facebook and continue browsing there. All good!
2. User in NOT logged-in to the facebook. He logs into your app, browse your app then logs out of it. Then, when he open the facebook.com why will he expect that he should be looged-in to facebook automatically? I think he wont think that and he'll login to facebook and continue.

The point is simple here-

- if user logs into facebook, he'll be logged-in until and unless he logs out from facebook.
- if user is not logged into facebook but logs into your app, he will be logged-in to the facebook until he logs out from your app.